# Не изменяется разрешение экрана в Linux Mint 17.1 (32-bit)

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Поставил я графический драйвер Nvidia-304 (рекомендуемый). Видеокарта GForce 7900 GT/GTO. Теперь при загрузке системы вылазит сообщение, мол, не удалось применить сохраненные настройки конфигурации экранов, а в настройке мониторов только одно разрешение - 640х480 и более слотов выбора разрешений нет. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Обновиться на более новый или слезть с бинарного на ванильный. Пробовал?

Comment: Только что обновил всю систему, не думаю, что есть более новые драйверы для моей системы.

Comment: Я не про ядра, а про версию дров от nvidia. aptitude search nvidia | grep -o nvidia-"[0-9A-F]\{3\}" | sort | uniq. Откатись на что-нить из этого.

Comment: Удалил все новые дрова, поставил nvidia-173 legacy binary. По крайней мере все заработало!

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа. Отметь галкой, если помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не работают предлагаемые драйвера, то есть 2 варианта:

1. Откатиться на разрабатываемый сообществом драйвер `nouveau`. Установить можно коммандой: `sudo aptitude -y install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`.
2. Поставить следующую или наоборот предыдущую версию закрытого драйвера от Nvidia. Список доступных версий можно узнать так: `aptitude search nvidia | grep -o nvidia-"[0-9]\{3\}" | sort | uniq`